# Как правильно прописать путь до Main.java?

Tags: java, maven

Пытаюсь собрать jar с помощью maven-assembly-plugin через командную строку (git bash) с помощью команды mvn compile assembly:single (выполняю в папке с pom.xml) - выдает ошибку:"Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher"
  Раздел build в pom.xml выглядит так:

```
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>

            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

Полный путь до Main.java такой: 
F:\Soft\9_Programming\2_Java_Android\stepic_java_webserver-master\L1.1 Simple web server_\src\main\java\main
Относительно файла pom.xml путь до Main.java такой: src\main\java\main\Main.java
Прописывал его в pom.xml src.main.java.main.Main - выдает ту же ошибку. 
В чем проблема?

Comment: Прописывать надо именно именно как main.Main, это правильный вариант. Но почему он не работает...

Answer (score 0):

Ты должен прописать путь (пакетов) к твой `Main.java` класс. [Тут ответ на твой вопрос](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)

Comment: Т.е. путь будет такой:  L1.1 Simple web server_.src.main.java.main.Main

Comment: http://java-course.ru/begin/packages/

Answer (score 0):

Может это вообще другой плагин ошибку выкидывает?
Скопируй себе это. Это кусок как из моего рабочего проекта

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>Name</finalName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

И собери "clean compile assembly:single"

Comment: Попробовал - та же ошибка выходит

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось переустановить Windows, после чего все заработало с первоначальными настройками.